# How to order by the result of combining multiple collect?

Tags: neo4j, sql-order-by, match, cypher, collect

I have a query like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[:Shout]->(b)
WHERE a.user_id=1
WITH b.post_id as b_post_id, a, b.post as b_post
MATCH (a)-[:Friend]->(c)-[:Shout]->(d)
WITH d.post_id as d_post_id, b_post_id, d.post as d_post, b_post
order by d_post_id desc, b_post_id desc
RETURN collect(distinct d_post) + collect(distinct b_post) as p
```

I want to return all posts that are from user and friend so I combine the 2 match
the first match `(a)-[:Shout]->(b)` will return posts from user and the second match `(a)-[:Friend]->(c)-[:Shout]->(d)` will return posts from friend.

The posts of `(a)-[:Shout]->(b)` are

```
post_id: 5, post: nana
post_id: 2, post: hi
```

The posts of `(a)-[:Friend]->(c)-[:Shout]->(d)` are

```
post_id: 6, post: lala
post_id: 4, post: hello
post_id: 3, post: hanson
```

So, when I `RETURN collect(distinct d_post) + collect(distinct b_post) as p`, it will be
`P: nana, hi, lala, hello, hanson`

It should be: `lala, nana, hello, hanson, hi` or `6,5,4,3,2`

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
MATCH (a {user_id:1})-[:Friend*0..1]->()-[:Shout]->(b)
WITH b.post_id as post_id, b.post as post ORDER BY post_id desc
RETURN collect(post) as posts
```

**Edit**

Per comment, if you want to return the id of the node that `-[:Shout]->(b)` you can add an identifier for the optional friend place

```
MATCH (a {user_id:1})-[:Friend*0..1]->(friendOrUser)-[:Shout]->(b)
WITH friendOrUser, b ORDER BY b.post_id desc
RETURN friendOrUser.user_id, b.post
```

Here `friendOrUser` binds both the user `a` and his friends.

Comment: it works but I forgot to tell that not only posts I want to return. I see your code returns posts well but when I tried to return username and friend it only return users that has `user_id:1` as you declared it in the query.

Comment: doesn't `(a {user_id:1})-[:Friend*0..1]->()-[:Shout]->(b)` mean user friend with itself?

Comment: No, it means match all shouts from a and from friends of a. With limiting property for `a` it will always be that individual node, but the unbound node place `[:Friend*0..1]->()` can hold both a and friends of a (following zero outgoing [:Friend] from a to reach a). Give that place an identifier and return it's values to get id of user and user's friends. Here, I'll update my answer.

Comment: yeah I already thought that. So `(a {user_id:1})-[:Friend*0..1]->()-[:Shout]->(b)` is different from `(a {user_id:1})-[:Friend]->()-[:Shout]->(b)` ?

at the first I used `(a {user_id:1})-[:Friend]->()-[:Shout]->(b)` but I should make users friends with itself

but after I wondered what user is friends with itself for
and then I asked it on stackoverflow and I got the solution and I just knew that a relationship can be like `[:Friend*0..1]`

Thank you so much. It really helps.

Comment: and I need your suggestion. What is better using `ORDER BY` before `RETURN` or after `RETURN`?

Before `RETURN` is like:
`MATCH (a {user_id:1})-[:Friend*0..1]->(friendOrUser)-[:Shout]->(b)
WITH friendOrUser, b
ORDER BY b.post_id desc
RETURN friendOrUser.username, b.post`

or after `RETURN` is like:
`MATCH (a {user_id:1})-[:Friend*0..1]->(friendOrUser)-[:Shout]->(b)
RETURN friendOrUser.username, b.post
ORDER BY b.post_id desc`

or they are both just the same?

Comment: In this case they are equivalent, so order the return. In your question you were returning a collection and the results had to be ordered before collecting. It's difficult to read code in comments, if you have more follow up you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. The query is not very clean but will do the job.

```
MATCH (a)-[:Shout]->(b)
WHERE a.user_id=1
WITH b,a
MATCH (a)-[:Friend]->(c)-[:Shout]->(d)
WITH b,d
MATCH (dummy) WHERE (dummy = b OR dummy = d) 
WITH dummy ORDER BY dummy.post_id DESC
RETURN collect(distinct dummy.post) AS p
```

Comment: it works but I think it's not efficient, so is there any ways to solve this problem? or is it better to use UNION than COLLECT?

Comment: sorting on aggregate of two collections is not possible currently as per my understanding. You can go for union but above query is better than UNION... You can try and test.. Anyway the logic for both of them is same rendering all the node properties in column form and then sorting on it as ORDER BY only takes properties of nodes or relationships

Comment: I know the query above is better than UNION but still not working in some conditions like when I change user_id into 2 or others, it returns no posts and when I try to return the user who posts it, it returns users only. it should be able to return the user and friend that user friend with.

Comment: if it works for user_id = 1 it should work for user_id=2, check the data... please post the query you are trying .. and a graph gist if possible..